# Virtualisation options on M1/M2/M3 Mac running macOS Sonoma

Tags: virtualization, sandbox

I am in need on virtualizing apps on Mac ARM running Sonoma.

As Parallels is out of the question due to restrictions on my end, I am in need of using another option.

VMWare's "player" doesn't support Mac OS at all, Virtual Box only supports Intel Macs, so I am a bit clueless how to proceed from here.

How can I virtualise macOS apps in macOS Sonoma?

Comment: “As Parallels is out of the question due to restrictions on my end, I am in need of using another option.” What restrictions? It is literally your only option nowadays.

Comment: As in "I cannot install it due to restrictions put up by my employer".

Answer (score 1):

> VMware Fusion delivers the best way to run Windows, Linux and more on
> Apple Macs without rebooting.
>
> Fusion 13 supports Macs with either Intel or Apple silicon running
> macOS 12 and newer, and includes features for developers, IT admins
> and everyday users.

Source: [Official VMWare Website](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/fusion-evaluation.html)

There's also [Fusion 13 Player](https://store-eu.vmware.com/vmware-fusion-13-player-5710167300.html)